# jquery function that hides/displays text based on a drop down list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi everyone and thanks in advance for the help. So I have been learning asp.net with C# over the past two weeks, and feel like I get it pretty well, but I am having some trouble with jQuery functionality. I was trying to set up a form that would have a drop down list and depending on the option selected a different account creation form would be displayed within its panel. I used the following code:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/FrontEnd.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPMainContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="AccountTypeDDL" runat="server" >
        <asp:ListItem>Resident Account</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Student Account</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>University Account</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:Panel ID="CreateStudentAccountPanel" runat="server" >
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Create Student Account"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="CreateUniversityAccountPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Create University Account"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="CreateResidentAccountPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Create Resident Account"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="ScriptContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPClientScript" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(function ()
        {
            alert('hi');
            //This hides all initial textboxes
            $('#CreateStudentAccountPanel').hide();
            $('#CreateUniversityAccountPanel').hide();
            $('#CreateResidentAccountPanel').hide();



            $('#AccountTypeDDL').change(function ()
            {
                //This saves some time by caching the jquery value
                var val = $(this).index.toString;
                //this hides any boxes that the previous selection might have left open
                $('Panel').hide();
                //This just opens the ones we want based off the selection
                switch (val)
                {
                    case '0':
                        $('#CreateResidentAccountPanel').show();
                        $('#CreateUniversityAccountPanel').hide();
                        $('#CreateStudentAccountPanel').hide();
                       break;
                    case '1':
                        $('#CreateStudentAccountPanel').show();
                        $('#CreateResidentAccountPanel').hide();
                        $('#CreateUniversityAccountPanel').hide();
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        $('#CreateUniversityAccountPanel').show();
                        $('#CreateStudentAccountPanel').hide();
                        $('#CreateResidentAccountPanel').hide();
                        break;

                }
            });

        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

can anyone tell my why my jQuery code is failing to hide the text within the nonselected panels? I am lost. Thanks again.

edit sorry messed up that last post:

```
`code`
 var val = $('#<= AccountTypeDDL.ClientID %>').index;
                //this hides any boxes that the previous selection might have left open
                $('Panel').hide();
                //This just opens the ones we want based off the selection
                switch (val)
                {
                    case 0:
                        $('#<%= CreateResidentAccountPanel.ClientID %>').show();
                        $('#<%= CreateStudentAccountPanel.ClientID %>').hide();
                        $('#<%= CreateUniversityAccountPanel.ClientID %>').hide();
                       break;
                    case 1:
                        $('#<%= CreateResidentAccountPanel.ClientID %>').hide();
                        $('#<%= CreateStudentAccountPanel.ClientID %>').show();
                        $('#<%= CreateUniversityAccountPanel.ClientID %>').hide();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $('#<%= CreateResidentAccountPanel.ClientID %>').hide();
                        $('#<%= CreateStudentAccountPanel.ClientID %>').hide();
                        $('#<%= CreateUniversityAccountPanel.ClientID %>').show();
                        break;
```

`code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `ClientID`

```
 $('#<%= CreateStudentAccountPanel.ClientID %>').hide();
 ....
```

Comment: Thank you! that makes sense. But.. while that worked for hiding the initial panels, even after I changed the syntax within the  switch statement, the drop down list does not effectively hide/show the different panels.

Comment: @Christian : Can you update your latest code in your question?

Comment: @Christian : So which part isnt working inthe updated code ? what is the value of this var  `val` ?

Comment: var val,  i assumed was storing the selected index of the account drop down list. The switch statement was supposed to hide the panels that don't correspond with the selected index and display the panel that does. However changing the selected item on the drop down list in the page does nothing at this juncture.

Comment: @Christian : You are getting my question wrong..what is the value in that variable ? check by placing an alert or debug

Comment: hm..it seems to be undefined, based on what alert() is saying.

Comment: Yes so instead can you try `$('#<= AccountTypeDDL.ClientID %>').val();` instead of `$('#<= AccountTypeDDL.ClientID %>').index;`

Comment: ah. I tried that and it still gives the message that it is {[native code]} and does not affect the visibility of the panels.

Comment: Am interested in knowing the value of that variable ..Have you tried to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

Load up the page in a good JavaScript debugger such as FireBug, and then try using the console to hide one if the sections by running this line:

```
$('#CreateResidentAccountPanel').hide()
```

If that doesn't work, use FireBug's html inspector to see what is the actual ID for the panel div. Asp.Net tends to add it's own junk ID's unless you explicitly tell it not to. To avoid this, add a `ClientIDMode="Static"` attribute into the panel tag definition:

```
<asp:Panel ID="CreateResidentAccountPanel" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Create Resident Account"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

I generally use Static for all ID's I know I'll be manipulating via jQuery - it makes life much simpler.

Comment: Forgot to add, using Static ClientIdMode also works for bigger projects where you have the JavaScript in its own file, whereas the #<%= CreateUniversityAccountPanel.ClientID %> type syntax only works where you have in the .aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like `#<%= CreateUniversityAccountPanel.ClientID %>`  as your selectors.